# Reverse function of dplyr::lag() which returns the offset based on the data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data about a simple order processing system with the daily number of incoming and outgoing finished orders. Here's some simplified data:

```
Date <- seq(as.Date('2018-01-01'), as.Date('2018-01-10'), by = "day")
In <- c(10, 6, 9, 5, 8, 4, 7, 12, 9, 7)
Out <- c(4, 7, 3, 8, 5, 6, 3, 9, 7, 4)
df <- data.frame(Date, In, Out)
```

For each date I want to calculate:

1. The work in progress.
2. The historic arrival date of the oldest orders that are still in progress.

Order processing follows the 'First In First Out'-rule.  We assume that the system starts with 10 pending orders from previous periods. It is then easy to calculate the work in progress `WIP` with dplyr:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(In.cumul = 10 + cumsum(In),
                Out.cumul = cumsum(Out),
                WIP = In.cumul - Out.cumul)
```

Leading to this output:

```
         Date In Out In.cumul Out.cumul WIP
1  2018-01-01 10   4       20         4  16
2  2018-01-02  6   7       26        11  15
3  2018-01-03  9   3       35        14  21
4  2018-01-04  5   8       40        22  18
5  2018-01-05  8   5       48        27  21
6  2018-01-06  4   6       52        33  19
7  2018-01-07  7   3       59        36  23
8  2018-01-08 12   9       71        45  26
9  2018-01-09  9   7       80        52  28
10 2018-01-10  7   4       87        56  31
```

My question is how to implement the second part above. The calculation would be this: For every value of `Out.cumul` look up the date when `In_cumul` reached that value (or just above) for the first time.

I'd like to avoid `For`-loops or creating a bespoke function and instead prefer a vectorized operation in dplyr. `lag()` and `lead()` in dplyr come closest, but the offset is not known here and has to be calculated from the data. So this would be some sort of reverse `lag()`-function.

The expected output is this:

```
         Date In Out In.cumul Out.cumul WIP     Oldest
1  2018-01-01 10   4       20         4  16 2018-01-01
2  2018-01-02  6   7       26        11  15 2018-01-01
3  2018-01-03  9   3       35        14  21 2018-01-01
4  2018-01-04  5   8       40        22  18 2018-01-02
5  2018-01-05  8   5       48        27  21 2018-01-03
6  2018-01-06  4   6       52        33  19 2018-01-03
7  2018-01-07  7   3       59        36  23 2018-01-04
8  2018-01-08 12   9       71        45  26 2018-01-05
9  2018-01-09  9   7       80        52  28 2018-01-06
10 2018-01-10  7   4       87        56  31 2018-01-07
```

An elegant solution using dplyr would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you interested only in `dplyr` answer or are open to base R as well?

Comment: Yes, open to base R as well. I tried subsetting and indexing using [brackets] but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `findInterval`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Oldest = Date[findInterval(Out.cumul, In.cumul, left.open = TRUE) + 1])
```

giving:

```
         Date In Out In.cumul Out.cumul WIP     Oldest
1  2018-01-01 10   4       20         4  16 2018-01-01
2  2018-01-02  6   7       26        11  15 2018-01-01
3  2018-01-03  9   3       35        14  21 2018-01-01
4  2018-01-04  5   8       40        22  18 2018-01-02
5  2018-01-05  8   5       48        27  21 2018-01-03
6  2018-01-06  4   6       52        33  19 2018-01-03
7  2018-01-07  7   3       59        36  23 2018-01-04
8  2018-01-08 12   9       71        45  26 2018-01-05
9  2018-01-09  9   7       80        52  28 2018-01-06
10 2018-01-10  7   4       87        56  31 2018-01-07
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map` from `purrr` to loop over each `Out.Cuml` and find the closest date when it crossed `In.cumul`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   mutate(Oldest = Date[as.integer(map(Out.cumul, 
                         function(x) which.max(In.cumul - x >= 0)))])


#         Date In Out In.cumul Out.cumul WIP     Oldest
#1  2018-01-01 10   4       20         4  16 2018-01-01
#2  2018-01-02  6   7       26        11  15 2018-01-01
#3  2018-01-03  9   3       35        14  21 2018-01-01
#4  2018-01-04  5   8       40        22  18 2018-01-02
#5  2018-01-05  8   5       48        27  21 2018-01-03
#6  2018-01-06  4   6       52        33  19 2018-01-03
#7  2018-01-07  7   3       59        36  23 2018-01-04
#8  2018-01-08 12   9       71        45  26 2018-01-05
#9  2018-01-09  9   7       80        52  28 2018-01-06
#10 2018-01-10  7   4       87        56  31 2018-01-07
```

---

In base R, we can use the same logic using `sapply`

```
df$Oldest <- df$Date[sapply(df$Out.cumul, function(x) which.max(df$In.cumul - x >= 0))]
```

Comment: Can you explain what gets passed to `map`? The `x` value, particularly.

Comment: @Nettle The first argument in `map` is passed in `x` so here it is `Out.cumul`.